# Pressure in water-filled universe

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics

Imagine an infinite universe completely filled with pure, liquid water. Would there be any local pressure?

I think there should be, since the moving particles would hit any imaginary surface continually.
But how could this pressure be calculated?

Comment: See if these are of any help- [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1548v1.pdf), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0212107)

Comment: _Infinite_ universe is problematic. For finite mass of fluid this problem is identical to that of a star, which is treated as a gravitating mass of gas (I am no expert in astrophysics).